# DQL - filter entitys bases on parent country

Tags: symfony, dql

I encounter a problem with a dql query.

To locate, I have protocols with a many to many relation with criterions,
criterions which have many to many relation with details,
details which have many to many relation with organes and then organes which have many to one relation with atelier which have a many to one relation with country.

I need to recover protocols which have NO country rattached or country which contains in an array. My problem is when a parent is null and other not, the entity is validate. I don't have many bases in SQL so I missunderstood something maybe.

THis is my DQL query :

```
    $queryBuilder->select('p')
        ->from($this->getClass(), 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.criteres', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.details', 'd')
    ->leftJoin('d.organes', 'o')
    ->leftJoin('o.atelier', 'a')
    ->where('a.country IN (' . $this->getUserCountriesFormated() . ') OR a.country IS NULL')
    ->orderby('p.name', 'ASC');
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Edit : an example of protocol which pull up because of a null detail (the country ITA isn't in my countriesformated array) :

[image: schema]

Comment: -> join only return country validated protocols, but I need also fresh created protocols without parents. If I inverse the query, I can't get these protocols too.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model seems to be a bit crazy (too many NtoN relationships), make sure it is correct. I suppose method `getUserCountriesFormated()` returns comma separated string of country ids, for example `"1,2,3"`.
Then, instead of

```
->where('a.country IN (' . $this->getUserCountriesFormated() . ') OR a.country IS NULL')
```

try to use:

```
->leftJoin('a.country', 'n')
->where('(IDENTITY(n) IN (' . $this->getUserCountriesFormated() . ') OR IDENTITY(n) IS NULL)')
```

Comment: Thnks for your response, I tried your code but It return me an exception (Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.). I don't know if this will correct my problem, Also I edit my post with a behavior which I don't want.

Comment: dyou need to post all your entitity files. also try to reduce problem to smaller one (so your select doesnt go through 6 entities). also post generated SQL (from log file)